# How can I convert an avif image file to a png file?

Tags: imagemagick, file-format

How can I convert an avif image file to a png file?

```
$ convert macadamiaCracker1.{avif,png}
convert: Decoder plugin generated an error: Unspecified (7.0) `macadamiaCracker1.avif' @ error/heic.c/IsHEIFSuccess/135.
convert: no images defined `macadamiaCracker1.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3325.
```

where

```
$ file macadamiaCracker1.avif
macadamiaCracker1.avif: ISO Media, AVIF Image
```

Was `convert`  updated to support avif after ImageMagick 7.1.0-45?

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-45 Q16-HDRI x86_64 d80f6a7cd:20220731 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fontconfig freetype heic jng jp2 jpeg jxl lcms lqr lzma openexr png raw rsvg tiff webp x xml zlib
Compiler: gcc (11.3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if a file is avif. If FILE.avif is avif, the results of `file FILE.avif` should be:

```
FILE.avif: ISO Media, AVIF Image
```

Convert an individual file from avif to png:

```
convert FILE.avif FILE.png
```

Convert all .avif files in a directory from avif to png:

```
for image in *.avif ;  do convert "$image" "${image%.*}.png" ; done
```

Comment: Thanks. Does `convert` in ImageMagick 7.1.0-45 support avif?

Comment: My ImageMagick in Ubuntu 22.04 is version 6.9.11.60, and the commands were tested with this version and work perfectly with avif files. I haven't tested the commands with version 7.1.0-45, but I used similar commands to convert files from avif to png with earlier versions of ImageMagick and they worked OK. btw the gThumb app in Ubuntu can view .avif files natively.

Comment: `no decode delegate for this image format `AVIF'`

Comment: I'm still getting the same error as OP, when I try to convert an AVIF to a JPG, using Ubuntu 23 with ImageMagick version 6.9.11-60. `convert-im6.q16: no images defined `assets/images/analogue_pocket_openfpga--title-card.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3229.
`

Comment: @RaleighL. It still works properly on my Ubuntu, so it's possibly a bug.

Comment: Identify ImageMagick version with `convert -version`. For me it shows `6.9.10` and this version does not support `avif` (Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04). Trying to update with `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` gives "imagemagick is already the newest version".

Comment: @Avatar I identified my ImageMagick version with `convert -version` in Ubuntu 22.04. For me it shows 6.9.11 and this version supports avif. I just tested it. How I got ImageMagick 6.9.11 in Ubuntu 22.04 is automatically because I am using Ubuntu Pro.

Answer (score 1):

even though you already have `convert` you need to run this install

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

then re-run your `convert` command

I had same error before running above install ... back then my `convert` version was

....................................

```
convert -version
GraphicsMagick 1.3.38 2022-03-26 Q16 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2022 GraphicsMagick Group.
Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.

Feature Support:
  Native Thread Safe         yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)     yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)    yes
  BZIP                       yes
  DPS                        no
  FlashPix                   no
  FreeType                   yes
  Ghostscript (Library)      no
  HEIF/HVEC ("HEIC")         yes
  JBIG                       yes
  JPEG-2000                  no
  JPEG                       yes
  JPEG XL                    no
  Little CMS                 yes
  Loadable Modules           no
  Solaris mtmalloc           no
  Google perftools tcmalloc  no
  OpenMP                     yes (201511 "4.5")
  PNG                        yes
  TIFF                       yes
  TRIO                       no
  Solaris umem               no
  WebP                       yes
  WMF                        yes
  X11                        yes
  XML                        yes
  ZLIB                       yes

Host type: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Configured using the command:
  ./configure  '--build' 'x86_64-linux-gnu' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--enable-libtool-verbose' '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--docdir=${prefix}/share/doc/graphicsmagick' '--with-gs-font-dir=/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts' '--with-x' '--without-dps' '--without-modules' '--without-frozenpaths' '--with-webp=yes' '--with-zstd=yes' '--with-perl' '--with-perl-options=INSTALLDIRS=vendor' '--enable-quantum-library-names' '--with-quantum-depth=16' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/graphicsmagick-vK5lFw/graphicsmagick-1.4+really1.3.38=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/graphicsmagick-vK5lFw/graphicsmagick-1.4+really1.3.38=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=a

Final Build Parameters:
  CC       = gcc
  CFLAGS   = -fopenmp -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/graphicsmagick-vK5lFw/graphicsmagick-1.4+really1.3.38=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall
  CPPFLAGS = -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libxml2
  CXX      = g++
  CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/graphicsmagick-vK5lFw/graphicsmagick-1.4+really1.3.38=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security
  LDFLAGS  = -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now
  LIBS     = -ljbig -lwebp -lwebpmux -lheif -lde265 -llcms2 -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -lpng16 -lwmflite -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -llzma -lbz2 -lxml2 -lz -lzstd -lm -lpthread
```

.................................

yet after running above install its now showing

```
convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are fine using a GUI program for that, then [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).

Comment: What, is this thread that much _imagemagick_-specific? It's not in the title. A lot of people will find this thread, also through web searches, for whom it does not matter whether a solution is constrained strictly to imagemagick or not. Some may even prefer a GUI solution.